# Searching Logs for Filename From List in a Directory w/ Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search text file content in a log directory for matching file names that exist in another directory.

I know I can do a `Get-ChildItem $Path -file -name` and get a list returned. I also know how to perform a `Get-Content ... | Select-String -Pattern`

However, I don't know how to feed the file list to the `-Pattern`.

What I've tried without success:

```
# Delete all Files in C:\Data\Uploads older than 90 day(s)
$Path = "C:\the_path"
$LogPath = "C:\logs"
Get-Content $LogPath + "\*.log" | Select-String -Pattern (Get-ChildItem $Path -name)
```

But I know this is just a blind attempt because `Get-ChildItem` is returning an iterative and not a usable pattern.

How can I do what I'm attempting to do and that is take a list of file names and recursively search for them in a directory of log files? #wishingitwasgrep

Comment: Do you mean `Get-ChildItem $Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`? That would return a string array containing only file names.

Comment: You should probably add `-SimpleMatch` to `Select-String` (so the filenames are used as literal matches rather than regular expressions). Other than that the code you posted should do what you want.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart `Get-ChildItem` has a `-Name` parameter that returns an array of the `.Name` property.

Comment: @John Giotta: `-match` basically functions like grep. `@(Get-Content -Path C:\mypath\*.log) -match 'pa\sttern'` this will filter all lines in every file that matches the `Get-Content` wildcard search.

Comment: Yes, I have a bias toward PSv2 syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-3.0) essentially *is* PowerShell's implementation of `grep`. Except it can't recurse by itself. That's where `Get-ChildItem` comes into play.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$LogPath\*.log" -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern (Get-ChildItem $Path -Name) -SimpleMatch
```

You can make the statement a little less verbose by using aliases as well as positional instead of named parameters (not recommended for use in scripts, though).

```
ls "$LogPath\*.log" -r | sls (ls $Path -n) -s
```

If you want a regular expression match instead of a simple string match remove the `-SimpleMatch` switch.

Comment: If it wasn't for the recursion, you could skip the first `ls` call and just do `sls -Path C:\logs\*.log`

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but here's something that should work:

```
@(Get-Content -Path C:\logs\*.log) |
    Where-Object { $_ -in @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\the_path -Name) }
```

Now you have a list of files.

---

> How can I do what I'm attempting to do and that is **take a list of file names and recursively search for them in a directory of log files?**

```
$List = Get-Content -Path 'C:\LogList.txt'

$LogList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Logs' -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in $List })
```

This assumes your `LogList.txt` has a newline separated list of log file names with an extension (such as `MyLog.txt`).  `$LogList` will then have an array of `System.IO.FileInfo` objects which you can utilize to do whatever you want with these files.  For example:

```
$LogList | Remove-Item
```